React useEffect works for the first time but I can't use it in another component when the browser renders
first of all, I'm not good at speaking english. so the senteces would be massy. I'm sorry for that..
Problem Description
I use context for handle Global state in React. I get some data from JWTtoken. The problem is that when i login into web site which i'm making, i can't get data which i set as i login into website.
Here's my code
import { createContext } from "react";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { jwtDecode } from "jwt-decode";

export const RoleContext = createContext({
  optionRole: "",
  setOptionRole: () => {},
});

const RoleProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [optionRole, setOptionRole] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
    if (token) {
      try {
        const decodedToken = jwtDecode(token);
        setOptionRole(decodedToken.role);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error decoding token:", error);
      }
    }
  }, []);

  const roleCtx = {
    optionRole,
    setOptionRole,
  };

  return (
    <RoleContext.Provider value={roleCtx}>{children}</RoleContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default RoleProvider;

import React, { useState, useEffect, useContext } from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { RoleContext } from "../store/role-context";
// reactstrap components
import pic1 from "../../assets/img/theme/team-4-800x800.jpg";
import {
  DropdownMenu,
  DropdownItem,
  UncontrolledDropdown,
  DropdownToggle,
  Navbar,
  Nav,
  Container,
  Media,
} from "reactstrap";
import { jwtDecode } from "jwt-decode";

const Navbar = ({ employeeName, setEmployeeName }) => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const { optionRole, setOptionRole } = useContext(RoleContext);

  useEffect(() => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
    if (token) {
      try {
        const decodedToken = jwtDecode(token);
        console.log("decodedToken :", decodedToken);
        setEmployeeName(decodedToken.name); // JWT 토큰의 payload에서 name 가져오기
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error decoding token:", error);
      }
    }
  }, []);

  console.log(`SuperAdminNavbar 에서 값 ${optionRole}`);

I get optionRole data from jwttoken and the state is set. when i use it another component which is Navbar, it said there's no any optionRole. However, when i refresh two or three times, it said there's optionRole. I don't know why...
To summary, when i login into web for the first time ${optionRole} is "". but i refresh two or three times i can get optionRole. How can i solve it?..
Thank you for your effort in advance
i'm expecting get the optionRole data simultaneously as the website is loading.

Could you post the login functionality :)

Dustaboy3 ~ Thank you for your comment I solved this problem :) as you expect, there's a problem in login components. i shoud've set optionRole in login components. I solved this problem by setting optionRole in login components. Hava a great day ~~

Great exactly where i was trying to lead you :D Good luck in the future
